# Disable application unistall in android?

Tags: android

I want to such a thing that when my app will install in a android phone. no body can uninstall it from phone, or when any one will try to uninstall it, a pop up show or any alert.
Is there any way ?

Comment: You don't want to let people uninstall your app from their phone? Scary...

Comment: Is their any way to make device administrator.
Mean if a user install application in android, other user can not delete that app from that device?

Comment: Wait on this one guys.. Sometimes phones are not owned by those using it.. If I owned a company and wanted my staff to use an app I had built for them, then I'd be rather miffed if they un-installed it.  Think parking ticket people, sales staff, delivery staff.  I own the hardware, and I say you use it.

Comment: @daveatflow..  i want to make this kind of thing. can you help me?

Comment: I think you might need to do some code altering in the os level.

Comment: @Niko Great quote... Impossible' is a word that humans use far too often.  Just cause we don't know how.. doesn't mean it can't be done.

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper  Sorry, I don't know how.. But I wanted to pre-empt the flames your request would surely get.. Locking users out of their phone pisses off our sense of fair.. But then locking a USP guy out of changing the apps on their name takey thing (usually a PPC), that isn't too hard to swallow.

Comment: Sure, nothing is impossible, but the level of knowledge needed for this kind of thing would be quite high, and seeing the amount of information, own research and effort in this question I doubt this is possible in this case, particularly not as a result of this question. I agree that this sort of thing might be a valid question in another form...

Answer (score 7):

You will need to enable deviceAdmin to disable `Force Stop` and `Uninstall` features. This is handled by the `Device Admin API` which handles enterprise/app policy management.

Comment: Can you please share sample code of Device Admin API to use this feature?

Answer (score 3):

Disabling explicitly is impossible. However, you can use a workaround for this.
Create a service in your app which runs persistently in background:

```
//MasterService.java
public class MasterService extends Service{

    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){}
    };

    public MasterService(){
        executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
                       new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    }

     @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        executor.execute(runnable);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        executor.shutdown();
    }

};
```

Don't forget to start it with `startService(new Intent(this, MasterService.class));` and declare it in your manifest as exported and enabled.

Android has (on non-rooted phones) to run the package manager in order to uninstall an app. 
In your `Runnable`, you need to detect whether the package manager is running in foreground. If yes, start an activity which takes input focus using a view:

```
//MasterService.java (inside runnable)
@Override
public void run(){
    while(true) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

        for (int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) {
            //check if package installer runs in foreground
            if (procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.android.packageinstaller") && procInfos.get(i).importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {

                //start activity
                startActivity(new Intent(MasterService.this, OverlayActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your activity, create any view and override the back button to prevent the user from getting back to the package uninstaller screen:

```
//OverlayActivity.java
public class OverlayActivity extends Activity{

    private ImageView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        view = new ImageView(this);
        setContentView(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }
};
```

Home button is not important, because it will hide all activities, and if the user presses the task button to choose the package manager, the `OverlayActivity` will be opened again.
Make sure that the master service can't be stopped or force-closed. There are two ways to solve this:

1. Send in your `onDestroy` function a custom broadcast message which launches your service again.
2. Disable the settings app too by checking for `com.android.settings`.

I hope you know what you do because the user should know when to uninstall an app.

Answer (score 1):

You could, theoretically, "root" the phone, add your application to the system partition (users can't modify the system partition) and then "un-root" the phone again. I'm not sure this will work with all models, though. Some devices can't be "un-rooted".

Comment: hmm can you explain how to root a phone. mean all the android manufacturer allow it? if not than which know manufacturer provide this feature?

Comment: Rooting a phone might be a very specific procedure for each device manufacturer. I don't think there is a tutorial to cover all different makes. You'll have to google for specific instructions I'm afraid. I know Sony Ericsson (Sony Mobile now-a-days) are very liberal in their approach to rooting (they have a very helpful community in their very own developers forum).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I currently think you could accomplish this is with two applications.

1. is the master.. it runs as a service, checking if an app is 
   installed and installs it if it's missing.
2. is the app you want your user to see

Ok.. well I can think of other ways.. As Blessenm said, alter the OS.. But that supposes you are targeting a specific bit of hardware.

You might be able to Root the system, and that could give you access to the admin idea.. Not sure if it would work.